# Customize Vim to have border on horizontal split

Tags: vim

I am always using multiple windows to edit multiple files. I can style my Vertical Split with

```
highlight VertSplit cterm=none gui=none
```

But what about styling horizontal split? I want it to have visible border, just like Vertical split does.

Something like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) can have it like this:
[image]

But with vim default configuration I can only clearly see vertical splits:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim always places a *status line* between two horizontally split windows (and potentially also at the bottom of a single window, depending on the `'laststatus'` option). You can style it via the corresponding highlight groups: `StatusLine` (for the currently active window) and `StatusLineNC` (for all other windows).

Comment: So i need to style 'StatusLineNC' , i already have vim airline plugin for my status line